# Streamlit blocked asking for credentials

Tags: python, windows, streamlit

I'm trying to deploy a Streamlit app to Windows. I managed to set up all the environment and dependencies and get it start (for the details on how I deploy the app, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352179/package-streamlit-app-and-run-executable-on-windows)). But it immediately blocks asking for credentials.

This is the log:

```
  Welcome to Streamlit!

  If you're one of our development partners or you're interested in getting
  personal technical support or Streamlit updates, please enter your email
  address below. Otherwise, you may leave the field blank.

  Email:
2021-10-11 20:56:53.202 WARNING streamlit.config:
Warning: the config option 'server.enableCORS=false' is not compatible with 'server.enableXsrfProtection=true'.
As a result, 'server.enableCORS' is being overridden to 'true'.

More information:
In order to protect against CSRF attacks, we send a cookie with each request.
To do so, we must specify allowable origins, which places a restriction on
cross-origin resource sharing.

If cross origin resource sharing is required, please disable server.enableXsrfProtection.
           
2021-10-11 20:56:53.202 DEBUG   streamlit.logger: Initialized tornado logs
2021-10-11 20:56:53.202 ERROR   streamlit.credentials:
```

It seems that the execution of the app is stopped becuase it is waiting for some credentials. I found [here](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/646) that a `.streamlit/credentials.toml` can be added, but I'm not sure on the exact location on windows. I've also tried to explicitly add `--server.headless=false` while launching streamlit, but again with no effect.

Why the app doesn't start automatically like on Linux, showing the address where the app can be reached? Is there a way to start the app without additional configurations by the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem overcome, I mistakenly set to `false` the `--server.headless` configuration. Instead, it must be `true`. Another argument is required to make the deploy work properly: `--global.developmentMode=false`.

Full anwser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69621578/16797805).