# Pynsist error: NoWheelError: No compatible wheels found for blinker 1.4

Tags: python, deployment, exe, streamlit, pynsist

I have built a web app by using streamlit. Now, I want to share my app to others without  deploying in the cloud. I tried to create an executable file by using pynsist. I followed the steps mentioned in this [Package streamlit app and run executable on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69352179/package-streamlit-app-and-run-executable-on-windows) and https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist/tree/master/examples/streamlit but I'm getting this error.

File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nsist\wheels.py", line 144, in get_from_pypi
raise NoWheelError('No compatible wheels found for {0.name} {0.version}'.format(self))
nsist.wheels.NoWheelError: No compatible wheels found for blinker 1.4.

Project structure:

```
|- src
    |- main.py
    |- run_app.py
|- wheels #empty folder
|- installer.cfg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because Blinker does not publish wheels on PyPI. Wheels are a common format for modern Python packages, but Blinker was last released in 2015, when it wasn't so normal to make wheels.

Blinker appears to be a simple, pure-Python package, so it should be easy to make a wheel of it locally, by running `pip wheel blinker==1.4`. Then you can tell Pynsist to use this with either the `extra_wheel_sources` option - giving it a directory of wheels to use in addition to PyPI for `pypi_wheels` - or the `local_wheels` option pointing to the specific `.whl` file.

See also [bundling packages which don't have wheels on PyPI](https://pynsist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#bundling-packages-which-don-t-have-wheels-on-pypi) in Pynsist's FAQ.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Just saw your answer and now it works. I added a few images in installer.cfg now I'm getting an error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.jpg' when I run the  app. Apologies for delayed response and Thanks.

Comment: You probably want another FAQ entry for that: https://pynsist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files

Comment: Can you elaborate more with an example? It would be helpful.

Comment: It might be worth making a new question with the details of that - it's a bit tricky to give much information in comments.